# How am i allowed to pass a method to List.Sort()?

Tags: c#, sorting, comparison

i am calling [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx) on a [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx):

```
List<Stuff> list = new List<Stuff>();
list.Sort(StuffSortByName);
```

with the `StuffSortByName` declaration of:

```
private static int StuffSortByName(Stuff x, Stuff y)
{
    ...
}
```

What surprises me is that my code compiles ***and*** works. It's surprising that no overload of `Sort` takes a method:

- [`Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx)
- [`Sort(Comparison<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx)
- [`Sort(IComparer<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx)
- [`Sort(Int32, Int32, IComparer<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ce6t5ad.aspx)

So i was fortunate, as i didn't want to have to create a whole object, that implements IComparer, just to sort stuff. But for the life of me i don't understand while it compiles.

---

And now i want to duplicate that magic. i want to sort a ListView. But you don't sort a listivew, you give a listview an `IComparer` through it's [`ListViewItemSorter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemsorter.aspx) property:

```
listView1.ListViewItemSorter = [IComparer]
```

And, again, i don't want to write a whole object, i just want to pass a local method (and ideally a non-static one):

```
listView1.ListViewItemSorter = SortListView;


private static int SortListView(Object x, Object y)
{
    ....
}
```

Now of course this doesn't compile because it makes no sense. But then the earlier syntax shouldn't compile either - but it does.

So it gives me hope that i can have the same confusing syntax here.

How was i allowed to pass a method as a sort comparer in the first case, but not in the second case?

Comment: Note that the first is matching on `Comparison<T>`, matching with a function that takes two T and returns an int. Pass it in delegate, a `Func<T, T, int>`, etc. The second version has a different expectation, an `IComparer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your first question, the reason the method name can be passed is because `Comparison<T>` is a delegate type, meaning it is a type representing a method signature. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) for details.

In your case, you should either create an `IComparer` object or have your `Stuff` object implement `IComparable` or `IComparable<T>` (if possible).

Comment: i completely missed that it was a delegate. i read it as i could pass an `IComparer`, or use the generic class `Comparison<T>` which implements `IComparer`. But `Comparison<T>` isn't a generic class...

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx). which uses [Comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx)

From link:

> If comparison is provided, the elements of the List(Of T) are sorted
>   using the method represented by the delegate

**EDIT**

What about `ListView`, as you noticed too, it implements `IComparer` and **not** `Comparison`, so you can not just pass a delegate to it.